# Finding examples that works for vector spaces over a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

Does anyone have examples in mind that following statements are true for vector spaces over a division ring, but need not be true for modules over an arbitrary ring?

> Every maximal linear independent set in a free module is a basis.
>
> Every minimal spanning set in a free module is a basis.
>
> Every quotient of a free module is free.

Comment: What do you mean by basis? the usual definitions go crazy quite fast!
and for the last one: $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: The last one is weird, considering vector spaces. *All* modules over division rings are free.